# Automatic date when clicking the add button

Tags: javascript

I created a table and I am using datatables to do insert, update and delete. 
When I add a new row in my table, the date column should fill in automatically with the date of the day after the last row entered. For example, the last row in the Date column has the following date, 03-07-2019, when you add a new row, the Date column should automatically receive the date 04-07-2019.

My code looks like this:

```
<div align="right">
     <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="alert_message"></div>
    <table id="user_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Data</th>
       <th>Resp. de Turno</th>
       <th>Apoio</th>
       <th>Elementos ALA A</th>
       <th>Elementos ALA B</th>
       <th></th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    </table>
```

Then the javascript to do insert:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
   var html = '<tr>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data1"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data2"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data3"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data4"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data5"></td>';
   html += '<td><button type="button" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button></td>';
   html += '</tr>';
   $('#user_data tbody').prepend(html);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#insert', function(){
   var data = $('#data1').text();
   var responsavel = $('#data2').text();
   var apoio = $('#data3').text();
   var elementos = $('#data4').text();
   var elementos1 = $('#data5').text();
   if(data != '' && responsavel != '' && apoio != '' && elementos != '' && elementos1 != '')
   {
    $.ajax({
     url:"./insert",
     method:"POST",
     data:{data:data, responsavel:responsavel, apoio:apoio, elementos:elementos, elementos1:elementos1},
     success:function(data)
     {
      $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
      $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
      fetch_data();
     }
    });
    setInterval(function(){
     $('#alert_message').html('');
    }, 5000);
   }
   else
   {

alert("Os campos são de preencimento obrigatório!");
}
});
```

The php on `insert.php` page:

```
if(isset($_POST["data"], $_POST["responsavel"], $_POST["apoio"], $_POST["elementos"], $_POST["elementos1"]))
{
 $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["data"]);
 $responsavel = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["responsavel"]);
 $apoio = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["apoio"]);
 $elementos = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["elementos"]);
 $elementos1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["elementos1"]);
 $query = "INSERT INTO raddb.mapas(data, responsavel, apoio, elementos, elementos1) VALUES('$data', '$responsavel', '$apoio', '$elementos', '$elementos1')";
 if(mysqli_query($conn, $query))
 {
  echo 'Data Inserted';
 }
}
```

Comment: You can use Date object with td, for example <td contenteditable id="data1">'+Date.now()+'</td>. More details : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now or https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-date-now/

Answer (score 1):

You can create class CellDate before "$('#add').click(function(){".

```
class CellDate{
    constructor( start_date ){
        this.date = start_date;
    }
    getNextDate(){
        this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() + 1);
        return this.date;
    }
}
```

After that create CellDate object with start date ( from post or manualy )

```
var DateIndexer = new CellDate(new Date(1999,11,31));
```

In event "$('#add').click(function(){" you can call "getNextDate()" to add new date.

```
html += '<td contenteditable id="data1">'+DateIndexer.getNextDate()+'</td>';
```

If you want to use a specific date format, for example: "yyyy-mm-dd". You can use it:

```
var now = new Date();
var formated_date = now.format("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

Comment: But he wished that if he did not have rows in the table he would start on the first day of the following month. But if the table already has rows, it takes the date from the column of the last row.  
The example you posted always starts on the current date.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but if you need anу else Day, you can create object with your data.